# Objective C: for in iterating but excluding object in array

Tags: objective-c

How can I iterate through an array for two objects to compare them, but at the second iteration (for obj2) I want to exclude comparing the object (obj1) that already was found
to match? In other words, I don´t want them to both find the same object.

```
for (object *obj1 in array) 
    if (obj1 == "this") //run next iteration
    for (object *obj2 in array)
    // if (obj2 == @"this");
```

Comment: If you are trying to keep the elements of your array unique, look at `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet` (if a strong order is also needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(object *obj1 in array) {
    for (object *obj2 in array) {
        if(obj1 == obj2) continue; //this matches if the object is same
        //do your code
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that == is a pointer comparison, which will only be true for the exact same object. If you want to also match different instances of an object with the same value, use `-isEqual:` instead.